# If $K=\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}$ and $L$ is the splitting field of $\prod_{i=1} ^{p-1} (t^2 -i)$ for odd prime $p$, find the Galois group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, galois-theory

> If $K=\mathbb{Z} /p \mathbb{Z}$ and $L$ is the splitting field of $\prod_{i=1} ^{p-1} (t^2 -i)$ for odd prime $p$, find the Galois group.

**My proof:**

Since $\left| \{ i^2 \mid i=1,...,p-1 \} \right| = \frac{p-1}{2}$,  there is some $i_0 \in \{1,...,p-1\}$ which is not a square in $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$

So $ t^2-i_0$ is irreducible over $K=$ $\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z}.$

A splitting field of $ t^2-i_0$ over $\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$

Since any irreducible polynomial of degree 2 over $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ ,  $t^2 -i$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ for every $i \in \{1,...,p-1\}$

Hence $L$ is $\mathbb{F_{p^2}}$ and its galois group  $ {\rm Gal}(L/K)=\langle{\rm frob}_p\rangle = \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ where ${\rm frob}_p$ is a Frobenius map for $p$

---

I am not sure if my proof is right.

Please feel free to leave any comments here, if the proof is not right, or you have simpler proof.

Comment: By the way, since $$\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(x-i)=x^{p-1}-1,$$ your polynomial is $t^{2(p-1)}-1=(t^{p-1}-1)(t^{p-1}+1).$ And the first factor already splits. So you want the splitting field of $t^{p-1}+1.$

Comment: Your answer seems fine.